# Does eager loading solve n+1 problem? (SpringBoot/hibernate)

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, lazy-loading, eager-loading

There are many articles about n+1 problem, but they usually start to explain how to solve it with custom methods.

My question is general: Does eager loading solve n+1 problem?

(in other words: does n+1 problem have a chance to appear when we use eager loading? Does n+1 problem have a chance to appear when loading is lazy only?)

You can consider I've a `Car` entity and `Collection<Wheel>` with `@OneToMany` relationship in it. Suppose I'm using SpringBoot > 2, Hibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, if my previous answers were not clear to you but you have already figured it out.

> the condition for n+1 problem is: Lazy fetching + existing session (to prevent the lazyinitializationexception)

So you should use "FETCH JOIN" or EntityGraph to avoid N+1 issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only these two entities, yes it solves N+1 issue. However, that's not always the case with real world apps. And if you continue using eager fetching for all relationships, it will cause other issues like over fetching.

Comment: Ok, got it, thank you. But when use Lazy fetching using, lazyinitializationexception will happen when I try to iterate the collection right? So the condition for n+1 problem is: Lazy fetching + existing session (to prevent the lazyinitializationexception), right?

Comment: `LazyInitializationException` happens only when you try to access the collection after session is closed.

Comment: See https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-handle-the-lazyinitializationexception/ for more detailed explanation.

Comment: I read his articles. It's mostly about how bad is open session in view. But I need to know basics first: So the condition for n+1 problem is: Lazy fetching + existing session (to prevent the lazyinitializationexception), right?

Comment: Not actually, you will still have one extra query. So depending on the use case, you can use `JOIN FETCH` to avoid extra query.

Comment: yes, due to articles I know how to avoid: JOIN FETCH. But my question is: Is the condition for n+1 problem appearing is: Lazy fetching + onetomany collection + existing session (to prevent the lazyinitializationexception), right? (my problem is: I know HOW to avoid, but don't know WHEN the problem appears)